# how to solve for length of diagonal board between columns

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I was watching a youtube video the other day and the guy was figuring out the length of a board needed to fit diagonally between two columns. He did it in an approximate way that worked fine, but it got me to thinking: how would one solve this mathematically?

[illustration of board between columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zr6gK.png)

So, let's call the space between columns "D", and the height "H" (to accommodate the diagonal board), and the width of the board "W". I'm looking for a formula into which you could plug these known dimensions, to compute "L" the overall length of the board, and I suppose the angle "A" of the cut on each end.

One can use the Pythagorean Theorem to compute the diagonal (of L x H), but this does not account for W (board width). Thus the board takes the shape of a parallelogram, sitting above a right triangle, the height of which is less than H. I believe this triangle is "similar" to the piece that would be cut off the end of the board (angles same, but perhaps smaller and rotated/flipped).

I've recognized an equation, H = W/Cos(A) + D*Tan(A), but I've no idea how to solve for A.

I'd greatly appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Calculate the diagonal of the board in two ways - with H and D and also with L and W.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$L=\sqrt{D^2+H^2-W^2}$, thank you Jaap

It now occurs to me that knowing the angle A is also important (or at least, knowing the other leg of the little triangles to cut off the ends).

$A=\arctan(\frac{H}{D})-\arctan(\frac{W}{L})$

Comment: You can let x be the other leg of the little triangle, and use similar triangles to eventually get a quadratic equation in x that you can solve. It is probably less error prone to calculate angle A by calculating the angles that the plank diagonal makes with the plank edge and with the ground, and subtracting them.

Comment: Thank you again!  A = Tan^-1(H/D) - Tan^-1(W/L), then x would be W*Tan(A)

Comment: That looks good to me.